# Escape program names in automake

Tags: automake

How can I escape program names in GNU automake? For example, the following works:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libc.la

libc_la_SOURCES = source.cc
```

However, if I try to use the symbol 'plus' (+) on the program name, like this:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libc++.la

libc++_la_SOURCES = source.cc
```

Make will respond with:

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'libc++.c', needed by 'libc++.lo'.  Stop.
```

It seems like it is not finding the SOURCES variable. I tried prepending the plus sign with the dollar ($), backslash (\) and double backslash (\\), without success.

Comment: A common swap for `c++` is `cpp` - as you've discovered, `+` cannot be used as part of a variable name, and I would strongly advise against trying - It'll get messy and confusing.

Comment: It's not true that `+` inside a variable name like this is a problem: it works fine from the perspective of GNU make. Problematic characters for GNU make variable names include `$`, `:`, `=`, and whitespace.  There are also some characters which need to be used with care if used at the _end_ of a variable name, such as `+`, `?`, and `!`; they can be used you just have to be sure you separate the name from the assignment: `foo? = bar` not `foo?=bar` which means something different.

Comment: You haven't shown us the important parts of this makefile: how these variables are _used_.  Based on the names here I suspect you're using them in an automake file not a pure makefile.  There _ARE_ restrictions on the names of variables you can use with automake, as described in its manual.  Automake variable names do generally have to be simple with no special characters.

Comment: You're right, I did not mention that I'm using automake. I updated the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

automake will simply replace all uncanny characters with underscores `_`, to generate variable names.
So to reference your `libc++.la` library in variable names, use the `libc___la` prefix (two (2) underscores for the `+` characters, another one (1) underscore for the `.` character).

Your `Makefile.am` snippet will thus look like:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libc++.la
libc___la_SOURCES = source.cc
```